# How to change directory to run .bat files from different drive?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have some .bat files that I run from the local directory (e.g. C:\Users\pozna001).  However, when I try and change the directory to a data drive using `cd F:\nrcs_project` to run the .bat files from a different location, I see that the command prompt does not recognize the `cd` command.  How can I change the directory in the command prompt so that I can run these .bat files from a different drive (i.e. a data drive connected to a server)?

[image]

Comment: Excellent use of a visual to convey the problem.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
CD /D F:\nrcs_project
```

Use the `/D` switch to change current drive in addition to changing current directory for a drive.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to go from a device to another (in your case from `C:\` to `F:\`, you need to type `F:` before/after you entered your `cd` command, so it will go on the `F` device. Otherwise, you can use the `/D` parameter of the `cd` function.

So to sum up,

```
$C:\Folder> F:
$F:\>cd F:\whatever
$F:\whatever>...
```

or

```
$C:\Folder> cd F:\whatever
$C:\Folder> F:
$F:\whatever>...
```

or

```
$C:\Folder> cd /D F:\whatever
$F:\whatever>...
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to type **F:** to change to the F:\ drive, then you can use the CD command

Or you can use the /D switch to do it all in one shot:

```
CD /D F:\nrcs_project
```

Answer (score 1):

[you can also use](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html):

```
pushd "F:\nrcs_project"
```

this will allow also to return to the previous direcotry with `popd`

Mind that it is a good practice to enclose paths with double quotes in case of special characters,spaces and so on..

Answer (score 0):

the command will look like following:

```
F: && cd nrcs_project
```

Answer (score 0):

Both solution above are correct.

The fastest is:

cd /d f:\nrcs_project

But you could change drive first, then the directory.

Use cd /? and it will show you all params.